# (iOS) Over the Air (OTA) testing, expire time?

Tags: ios, ota, over-the-air

I've made a "Over the Air" download link for my app.
I did this by following this instructions: http://www.imjameshall.com/2012/04/ios-ota/ (Make archive, distribute "Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc option" etc).

Everything worked fine, app is installed and works perfectly.
Now my question is how long will this app work? I heard something about a month, a year, whats true about this?

Answer (score 0):

Ad hoc provisioning profile is having a validity period of an year. So your app will work for the same amount of period and you will have to renew it after that.